# how to handle exit code for multiple sequential unix command in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am need of shell script which have multiple commands like
Command -1  mv
command 2- cp
command -3 - sed
command -4 echo ,append etc
rc=$?
if =0 success
else
exist30

but even though move command failed script retuning return code as 0 and script showing success message.

Do i need to main RC for all the command or can i better handle return code for each command to make sure every command run successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with commands which may fail you can do the following:

```
if mv ...; then 
  echo mv success
else
 echo mv failure
 rc=1
fi
exit 1
```

For having your script to crash with the first failed command make sure to add the line `set -e` below your shebang (`#!/bin/sh`).
Keep in mind that the error handling above is compatible with `set -e`, the script will not stop.

`set -eu` is considered best practice for shell scripts, `-u` will result in a crash of your script if a variable used is unset.